# Adding percentage to number in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to add a percentage sign after a number in SQL.

This is the query I have

```
select cast(vetted as float)/cast(account_create as float)*100 from numbers
```

I have tried using the format function to change the integer to a string and concatenate the percentage sign, but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Redshift?  They are quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(vetted AS FLOAT) / CAST(account_create AS FLOAT) * 100, '%')
FROM numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following :

```
select CONCAT(cast(vetted as float)/cast(account_create as float)*100,'%') from numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function concat_ws to place a delimiter between a concat of number and delimeter number